# Use views result to send data to a rule

Tags: views, rules

I have a custom view that display several email address.
How I can use these addresses to send it an email with a rule?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This module will help you [views_rules](http://drupal.org/project/views_rules)

From module page:

> **View loop**
>
> A view loop is similar to a regular Rules loop, but allows looping
>   over rows of view results.
>
> **Collect view result rows (action):**
>
> This action collects each variable in all view result rows into list
>   variables for use in Rules.

Comment: Thanks!
I'm trying...
I can extrapolate the email to send a message. But there is a way to use the also other fields (title, name) to compose a custom message?

I'm sorry but I'm a newbie to drupal!

Comment: @vincenzodb of course you can create a custom message. You just need to add title and name fields to the view, and use those fields in the custom message.

Answer (score 5):

See subhojit777's answer first. views_rules is a good module I guess but I have personally used [Views Bulk Operations](http://drupal.org/project/views_bulk_operations) with Rules module and the outcome was *great*!

When Rules and Views Bulk Operations (VBO) modules are present, you will see the integrations in both ends. 
You can use a Rule (to be clear, a Rules Set) as an action for a VBO form. You can basically, for example,  have a button and a table with a list of nodes and checkboxes so you can choose a set of nodes and click the button to run the Rules set on the chosen nodes. 
In other words, execute a Rules Set on a selection of items using VBO module.

You can do this from the other side as well.

Create a View, and you will see an action to execute a Rules Set on a View using Rules itself. 
For an example, you can promote all blog nodes made *by the current user* to the front page when the user updates his account.

This can be done by creating a Rules Set that promotes given node to the front page, and a View that lists all blog nodes from a given user ID contextual filter , and a Rule that runs when the user profile is updated.

Johan from nodeone.se has a really nice set of videos about this:
http://nodeone.se/en/using-rules-components-with-vbo . You will see many videos in nodeone.se site.

Good luck!

Comment: Thank Ayesh!
I know VBO, but I have not found a way to make it work in the backend automatically.
 I'm sorry but I'm a newbie to drupal

Comment: Did you see nodeone.se videos ? If you have a few hours, go ahead and watch the videos. I'm sure they will help you to get started.